# No POST/boot with RAM installed

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, hardware-failure

This PC I am troubleshooting was built in 2009/10, with some HDD&SSD swaps since then.    everything else still from back then.
A month ago it hang up and had to be shut off manually. Didn't boot or POST since.
In the process of diagnosing (and hoping its the motherboard so it can be upgraded), it was determined that the motherboard is alive - the speaker signals when no ram is installed. When at least one stick is reinstalled, the speaker remains silent, fans spin, no boot/post.

Any thoughts as to why?

UPD1: tried switching channels/slots with 1 stick inserted, no go. The blue power light blinks with a pause (•--•--), fans spin up and slow down. Will probably have to try a new stick, as it would be easier than finding a donor or testbed.

UPD2: the startup config is mobo (DP55WB)+CPU (i3-530)+fans+(RAM (DDR3 10600)). I believe the memory controller is on the CPU. Presumably, the "no RAM" signaling when RAM removed rules out the CPU?

UPD3/4: got some hands on a PC3-12800 4gb plank (mine was 10660), installed in Slot0 - no effect. Memory controller dead?---the RAM was Single sided, not supported by the memory controller.
UPD5: put the jumper into setup, post card stopped at 24 - setting DIMM timings. After that went back to cycling 27 (RAM-related) and unknown post codes. Must be RAM

Comment: The RAM could be defective or the slot could be defective. Try placing the RAM in a different slot or try a different RAM module that can work with this motherboard.

Comment: It could still be anything from the RAM all the way to the memory controller. The memory controller might be built into the processor or motherboard at that age. With so little sign of life the only thing you can do is try the RAM in another system to see if it still works, then do the same with the processor. Given the age of the PC finding a donor system is going to be your biggest problem.

Comment: A similar issue is also discussed here http://superuser.com/questions/40744/blinking-power-button

Comment: The assumption is you are trying to power on with a CPU as well?  I did not see the exact startup/test configuration mentioned.

Comment: It would really help to know what technologies we're talking about here. A PC built in 2009 could have used any technology available then. We don't even know if it's an Intel or an AMD CPU, whether the memory controller is on the CPU die or the motherboard, or anything else. What memory technology?

Comment: It could also be a GPU or power supply problem. Try replacing that if you can.

Comment: GPU is disconnected and I doubt it is affecting anything. The PSU self-tests ok and gives enough current for booting+HDD+CD-ROM+GPU